# Cannot load Python REPL in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10 and Anaconda 5.1.0, Python 3.6 64 bit.

I installed VS Code using the default Anaconda installer (added feature on 2/17/2018). Then, I tried to load the Python REPL (control + shift + P, then Python: Start REPL). However, nothing happened; in the terminal below, it's just Windows Powershell.

I also created the following python code snippet, and it can run perfectly with F5 or control + F5. It should indicate that my Python set-up is correct. However, I still cannot use the Python REPL.

[image]

When I open the Developer Tools, I saw:

```
/C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:253 [Extension Host] Python Extension: Failed to get conda environment list from conda null
t.log @ /C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:253
console.ts:123 [Extension Host] rejected promise not handled within 1 second
t.log @ console.ts:123
t._logExtensionHostMessage @ extensionHost.ts:394
(anonymous) @ extensionHost.ts:211
emitTwo @ events.js:106
emit @ events.js:194
process.nextTick @ internal/child_process.js:766
_combinedTickCallback @ internal/process/next_tick.js:73
_tickCallback @ internal/process/next_tick.js:104
mainThreadExtensionService.ts:43 [ms-python.python]Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
e.$onExtensionRuntimeError @ mainThreadExtensionService.ts:43
e._doInvokeHandler @ rpcProtocol.ts:174
e._invokeHandler @ rpcProtocol.ts:159
e._receiveRequest @ rpcProtocol.ts:108
e._receiveOneMessage @ rpcProtocol.ts:90
(anonymous) @ rpcProtocol.ts:33
(anonymous) @ rpcProtocol.ts:213
e.fire @ event.ts:142
(anonymous) @ ipc.net.ts:81
emitOne @ events.js:96
emit @ events.js:191
readableAddChunk @ _stream_readable.js:178
Readable.push @ _stream_readable.js:136
onread @ net.js:560
mainThreadExtensionService.ts:44 TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at CondaService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shawn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.1.0\out\client\interpreter\locators\services\condaService.js:130:44)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Shawn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.1.0\out\client\interpreter\locators\services\condaService.js:13:58)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: It's a bug. Please file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python